# Is it 'German-born' or 'Germany-born'? Which one is correct in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

While searching for some keywords, I accidentally found keywords "German-born American poet" and it shows me the following page:
[image]

Now, I have a confusion. It should be 'Germany-born' rather than 'German-born'. As an SEO guy, I know, we can take certain liberty while searching terms on the Internet as Mr. Google can understand what we exactly want to find... But then, it is written in a few [articles](http://www.globalclue.com/clue/German_born_British_psychology_professor_noted_for_his) as well.

Is 'German-born' is correct or not?

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [Does “Vietnamese-born Australian” include child born in Australia by Vietnamese immigrants?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/65619/)

Answer (score 3):

To say that someone is

> **German born**
>   ***nationality*** *born*

means they are German *and* born in Germany, in your example

> **German born American**

means Charles was born in Germany but has US citizenship, he may or may not have American parents. Or similarly

> **American born Chinese**

means one is of Chinese ethnicity, but born in America, which by birth right makes them American.

You would not say

> **Germany born**

but rather

> **born in Germany**
>   *born in* ***country***

Comment: If I say, 'Germany-born American' then it implies that one has American ethnicity but born in Germany. Is it okay to write?

Comment: Yes, usually additional context would be understood. "***German-born American***" could mean both parents are from America (as in a military family) but could also mean a German national who is living in America as an American citizen.

Comment: I am asking about 'Germany-born American'. What does it imply? Your comment clears my views about 'German-born American'. Can we write 'Germany-born American' as per the relevant context?

Comment: @RucheerM  You can write it and it would be understood, but it is not usually used.  If you want to use the *country name*, you would say "American born in Germany".

Answer (score 1):

To indicate that a person was born in a particular country, we would use the *adjectival form of the country name*

> American-born
>
> German-born
>
> French-born
>
> South African-born
>
> Chinese-born
>
> Norwegian-born

unless the country name ends in **land**

> Icelandic-born <sup>possible but some would not use it</sup>
>
> Greenlandish-born <sup>no</sup>
>
> Swazilandian-born <sup>no</sup>

in which case we would most likely (but not always) use the country name itself (or a prepositional phrase, born in {country name} )

> Newfoundland-born painter ...
>
> Iceland-born actor...
>
> Swaziland-born singer
>
> New Zealand-born director ...

It would depend on whether we mean the person was born *into a nationality* or we mean to say *where* (in which country) the person was born.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that _-land_ exception? I'm finding plenty of online references for [Icelandic-born](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Icelandic-born%22&start=10) and I'm not convinced they are all wrong. Maybe it's a stylistic option?

Comment: You have to read what I write, @J.R.   "we would **most likely** use the country name itself..."

Comment: To me, the superscript "no" implies that it's incorrect.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll change it.

Comment: If this is a rule than why we have 'England-born actors', and not 'English-born actors'? It would help me if you elaborate your answer.

Comment: For India, I could find both 'India-born' and 'Indian-born'; so, which one is proper?

Comment: @Rucheer M: If *what* is a rule?